# Can boost::async be used with an Executor with Visual C++?

Tags: c++, boost, visual-studio-2015

I'm getting an error about a deleted function deep in boost with the code below only with Visual C++. (VS 2015 
update 2. I also tried preview of VS 15 but it's the same)

Latest versions of Clang and GCC are OK with this but perhaps VS is just more strict but indeed correct?

```
#define BOOST_THREAD_PROVIDES_FUTURE
#define BOOST_THREAD_PROVIDES_FUTURE_CONTINUATION
#define BOOST_THREAD_PROVIDES_EXECUTORS

#include <boost/thread/future.hpp>

class TestEx {
public:
    void submit(std::function<void()>) {
    }

    bool try_executing_one() {
        return false;
    }

    bool closed() {
        return false;
    }

    void close() {
    }
};

int main()
{
    TestEx tex;
    boost::async(
        tex,
        []() {});

    return 0;
}
```

If you would like to try compiling this but don't have access to Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 and boost you can do so online here.

http://rextester.com/BAX37541

Comment: Try replacing your `submit` function with `template <typename Closure> void submit(Closure&) { }`
It looks like accepting a `std::function` is triggering a copy of a noncopyable type. I wouldn't be surprised if this were an MSVC bug. Their implementation of `<functional>` has been known to needlessly copy, but I haven't unwound the template spew enough to point fingers.

Comment: If you want to continue using `std::function`, [`boost::executor_adaptor`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.executors.ref.executor_adaptor) will wrap your class (which adheres to the `Executor` concept) and perform the conversion to `std::function`. http://rextester.com/edit/IZN86995 The differences between the `Executor` concept and `boost::executor` are talked about [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.executors.rationale.closure).

Comment: Thank you for the excellent suggestion. Templating the `submit` function does appear to work. Looking forward to trying it out later in the production code. It would be nice to be able to debug template expansion somehow to work out what exactly is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Sean Cline pointed out the answer is to use `boost::executor_adaptor`